# Match occurance of pattern within a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm having some trouble matching a whole pattern within a string with the following regular expression and I'm not sure why:

```
pattern = "^.*\\b"+variable+"\\b.*$"
found = re.search(pattern, word)
```

I want to match the exact pattern (for example, the variable can be C/S or C/Strip, so it needs to match the full word C/Strip if it's there).

For example, word could be:

```
1.00C/S
100C/S
100C/Strip23
```

The word can also just be C/Strip or C/S on it's own.

Any pointers as to where I may be going wrong?

EDITED: For example, I want to match variable C/S in the word 100C/S

Comment: Example string where it fails to match what you want? Also example "words" where it fails?

Comment: Just edited the question, variable C/S fails to match in 1.00C/S. Basically I want it to match the occurrence of the pattern regardless of what is in front or behind it.

Comment: word boundary, so it matches the whole pattern within the boundary

Comment: Are you aware that your current pattern would match __EVERYTHING__ from the beginning of the line to the end?

Comment: And where are the boundaries in the string "word"?

Comment: Ah stupid mistake, I basically want to only match the word within the boundary and ignore anything before/after

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the pattern `"^.*\\b"+variable+"\\b.*$"` you are

1. matching the whole string (`.*`) and
2. you have to escape special characters in the variable

From the way you formulated your question I assume that you just want to match the specific text in the `variable`. To achieve this you have to change your pattern.

Try something like this:

```
re.search(re.escape(variable), word)
```

For a variable `C/S` this would only match `C/S` in a string like `1.00C/S`. If you want to match any characters before/after that (no whitespace, no numbers) it could look like this:

```
pattern = r"[a-zA-Z]*" + re.escape(variable) + r"[a-zA-Z]*"
re.search(pattern, word)
```

Take a look at the regular expression in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/sF3tP4/1).

---

You can also be less restrictive by explicitly forbidding specific characters (for example allowing anything **but** whitespace or numbers):

```
pattern = r"[^\d\s]*" + re.escape(variable) + r"[^\d\s]*"
re.search(pattern, word)
```

(See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/zN3sB6/1).)

Comment: Also tried this solution and it also works, thanks for the assistance!

Comment: If it works for you I would be grateful if you accept my answer as correct.